# How can I override settings in subprojects in an SBT project with multiple subprojects

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I have a project with with subprojects added as git submodules in subdirectories, each independent projects having their own `build.sbt` files. The root projects depends on and aggregates these subprojects. How can I override a setting value (e.g. `organization` or `version`) inside those subprojects?

```scala
lazy val p1 = (project in file("p1"))
  .settings(organization := "xyz.abc") // This does not work :(

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(p1)
  .aggregate(p1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting state overrides in  [`onLoad`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Startup.html#How+to+take+an+action+on+startup) which is

> of type `State => State` and is executed once, after all projects are
>   built and loaded.

For example,

```
lazy val settingsAlreadyOverriden = SettingKey[Boolean]("settingsAlreadyOverriden","Has overrideSettings command already run?")
settingsAlreadyOverriden := false
commands += Command.command("overrideSettings") { state =>
  if (settingsAlreadyOverriden.value) {
    state
  } else {
    Project.extract(state).appendWithSession(
      Seq(
        settingsAlreadyOverriden := true,
        subprojectA / organization := "kerfuffle.org",
      ),
      state
    )
  }
}

onLoad in Global := {
  ((s: State) => { "overrideSettings" :: s }) compose (onLoad in Global).value
}
```

`settingsAlreadyOverriden` is necessary for [Avoiding recursive `onLoad` execution #3544](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3544)

Related questions

- [SBT: Override setting in multi-build dependsOn/aggregate project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955217/sbt-override-setting-in-multi-build-dependson-aggregate-project)
- [How can I apply setting changes on onLoad hook in SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760279/how-can-i-apply-setting-changes-on-onload-hook-in-sbt)

Comment: Thank you very much @Marco! This works like a charm. Is there a difference between setting `Global / onLoad` inside of a subproject `settings` versus in the global scope of the main `build.sbt`, except the obvious non-determinism of lazy evaluations?