# SBT Dynamic Project Dependency

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager, sbt-plugin, sbteclipse

I recently need to integrate some projects as submodules, and each of them has its own build.sbt.
And there are also dependencies between submodules.
Therefore, I need to dynamically convert the libraryDependencies to dependsOn format.

The project structure looks like this, and root depends on A and B, while A also depends on B.

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── projA
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── src
├── projB
│   ├── build.sbt
│   └── src
└── src
    └── main
```

Since it seems appends .setting/.denpensOn directly to a project that already has build.sbt is ineffective.

```
//  ./build.sbt
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .dependsOn(A, B)

lazy val A = (project in file("projA"))
  .settings(commonSettings)        <-- not work
  .dependsOn(B)                    <-- not work

lazy val B = (project in file("projB"))
  .settings(commonSettings)        <-- not work
```

So, I try this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384866/how-can-i-override-settings-in-subprojects-in-an-sbt-project-with-multiple-subpr) to dynamically edit libraryDependencies, but this approach is only able to modify settings.
The inter-project dependencies seem to be not controlled by the settings.

Is there any way to dynamically add dependsOn to the project?
Or how to make the `depensOn` appended on the subproject in the root build.sbt works?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure there is API for that. I hoped something like https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/772f2ac65e0365fcbdcb82d74ac16586 can work but it doesn't so far. Maybe class loaders should be set up too.